# Given a vector $y$, what does $A^{T}y < 0$ imply in a linear algebra sense and a geometric sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a vector $y$, what does $A^{T}y < 0$ imply in a linear algebra sense and a geometric sense?

How does it relate with nontrivial solutions to $Ax = 0$ where $x \geq 0$ in both the linear algebra and geometric sense?

I think the second statement says the intersection of $n$ planes is the unique solution $x$ of $Ax = 0$ when $A$ is non-singular.

Comment: Please note: If $A\in F^{m\times n}$ with $n>1$ (for a field $F$), $A^T y<0$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question. Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-zero vector and $A\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $A^Ty\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is $<0$ when each component is.

We may consider that $\Pi=y^{\perp}$ is an affine hyperplane through the origin; its complement is constituted of two open convex parts $C^+,C^-$. Assume, for example, that the "head" of the vector $y$ is in $C^+$. Then $A^Ty<0$ is equivalent to say that the heads $(h_1,\cdots,h_m)$ of the $m$ column vectors of $A$ are in $C^-$. Moreover the convex hull of the $(h_i)$ is included in $C^-$.

Conversely, if you know $A$ and if you want to obtain the vectors $y$ s.t. $A^Ty<0$, then (in theory), you seek an affine hyperplane $\Pi$, through the origin, s.t. the $(h_i)$ are all in one of the components $C^+,C^-$.

About your second question, I think that you confuse with Farkas'lemma.